# Do you trust timestamps when they are out of order?

Tags: apache2, apache-log-files

When Apache2 log file entries have timestamps that are out of order, do you trust the timestamp or the order?

```
10.1.10.250 - - [20/May/2015:00:43:53 -0600] "GET /foo/bar_1234.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 738542 "http://www.example.com/foo/bar/jbcore/full.html" "some UA"
10.1.10.250 - - [20/May/2015:00:43:55 -0600] "GET /foo/bar_2345.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 824394 "http://www.example.com/foo/bar/jbcore/full.html" "some UA"
10.1.10.250 - - [20/May/2015:00:43:57 -0600] "GET /foo/bar_3456.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 15680 "http://www.example.com/foo/bar/jbcore/full.html" "some UA"
10.1.10.250 - - [20/May/2015:00:43:53 -0600] "GET /foo/bar_4567.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 822449 "http://www.example.com/foo/bar/jbcore/full.html" "some UA"
10.1.10.250 - - [20/May/2015:00:43:57 -0600] "GET /foo/bar_5678.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 15062 "http://www.example.com/foo/bar/jbcore/full.html" "some UA"
10.1.10.250 - - [20/May/2015:00:43:56 -0600] "GET /foo/bar_6789.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 798119 "http://www.example.com/foo/bar/jbcore/full.html" "some UA"
10.1.10.250 - - [20/May/2015:00:43:54 -0600] "GET /foo/bar_7890.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 836622 "http://www.example.com/foo/bar/jbcore/full.html" "some UA"
10.1.10.250 - - [20/May/2015:00:44:20 -0600] "GET /foo/bar_8901.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 763120 "http://www.example.com/foo/bar/jbcore/full.html" "some UA"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may seem odd, however, there may be a valid explanation.

Apache can log either the access (start) time or the completion time. At one point, when the feature to select access or completion time was new, Apache changed the default from access to completion, but when the inevitable backlash came, quickly changed the default back to access time. However what did not change as a result of the new feature is that regardless of which log time you select, it is always written to the log file at completion rather than when first accessed. Prior to this, all accesses were logged immediately even if they never really completed. The new method results in a cleaner log file.

So what happens now is that if a request takes a while to complete, it is written to the log file when it is completed which can be several seconds after it was started- hence the access times being out of order slightly. This is not that unusual since sometimes requests can take a few seconds to complete from time to time. However, if this is consistent throughout your log file, I would be looking into whether your server is taking too long to process requests or if there are specific requests that take too long. Otherwise, I would not worry about it at all.

Comment: Thank you, sir!  Perfect explanation and my mind is now at ease.  Those log entries are from a hosting provider, so if it gets prevalent I'll ask them to move us to a server with better response times!

Comment: In fact, as I look more closely at the out-of-order entries, it makes even more sense: Those URLs would have been more helpful if I hadn't shortened them so much. In-order timestamps were on /foo/thumbnails/bar....jpg and out-of-order timestamps were on /foo/images/bar...jpg.  Huge difference in bytes transferred, so your explanation of "timestamped at time request was seen; log entry written at completion" is spot on!

Comment: @jtoly For what it is worth, I use http://www.smalleranimals.com/thumb.htm to lean out my images. These people are real experts in image efficiency (that is all they do) and I have been using their software for about 15 years. You can use the software in trial mode for a period or pay the whopping fee of ... wait for it ... $15. Really. There is nothing better for making images smaller without loss of quality. This may help with downloads at least somewhat. It certainly does not hurt to try it anyway!!